# Pass CMake configuration options to 'conan build' on the command line

Tags: c++, cmake, package-managers, conan

I know CMake configuration options can be specified in `conanfile.py` in the `build` step. But is there a way to pass cmake configuration options to `conan build` directly via the command line?

A rough workaround for, say, build type could be something like:

```py
def build(self):
    cmake = CMake(self)
    cmake.definitions["CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE"] = os.environ.get("CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE", "Debug")  # specify here
    cmake.configure()
    cmake.build()
```

which can then be called like this

```
CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release conan build {BUILD_DIR}
```

But is there away to do this generally for any configuration option? I know it can be done at the `conan install` level via `-s` but that to my knowledge is only for dependencies and in any case I'm not interested necessarily in them being in Debug mode, I only want to configure it for the current project I'm building.

The `conan build` [docs](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/commands/development/build.html) only allude to this being possible in `conanfile.py::build` and there doesn't seem to be a command line option that allows to you to directly pass CMake options.

I know I can just defer to calling `cmake` directly and call that instead but was wondering if it was possible at all to do via `conan build`.

Comment: The "modern" way (albeit experimental) is to use ``generate()`` method and toolchains like ``CMakeToolchain`` (https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/tools/cmake.html), to generate the files needed for the build at ``install`` time, then building in the command line with ``cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=conan_toolchain.cmake`` is simple, and exactly the same build than when doing ``conan create`` is achieved.

Comment: @drodri oh, I had no idea at all there was a more modern conan flow, can you point me to resources or just information that motivates it and compares it with current/legacy ways? I'd be interested to read up on it and understand how/why it's better.

Comment: It is part of a major effort, which is the Conan 2.0. You can check the [Tribe 2.0](https://conan.io/tribe.html) some [migration guidelines here](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/conan_v2.html) and one (there might be more related) [blog post here](https://blog.conan.io/2021/10/19/New-CMake-Transparent-Integration-Guide.html)